# In Rails, why "action_controller/benchmarking.rb" is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, benchmarking

While checking why a page is loading fairly slowly, I saw that

```
/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb
```

is being run.  Why is it running (is it something in the config file?  or is it something standard in development mode?)

Won't it cause a page to load extra slow?  Is there a way to turn it off?  (using Rails 2.2.2)

Comment: are you running any benchmarks or performance tests ? How did you find out that benchmark.rb was being used ?

Comment: because some method is missing, and the stack trace shows it... by the way, what about the log that says: "Completed in 10ms" -- don't they require the benchmarking.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking is on by default in all environments. It's only doing quick basic time calculations for output into the logs.

2.2.2 is very old, I strong recommend upgrading to at least the last versions of 2.3.

It is unlikely that the built in benchmarking is slowing the page down. What else do the logs say? Are you in some way unhappy with 10ms response times?

Comment: the 10ms time is what the log says, but Firefox's Net panel is reporting 600ms to 1.0 second for the page to load, even when I just print out a "hello world"...  if it is a real page with content, then it can take 30 to 40 seconds, so that's why I am looking into some place where it might be causing the time taken.

Comment: Is firefox saying it's 600ms+ "time to first byte", or for the whole page load? Is this in production or in development? Which app server are you using? (Webrick, Mongrel, Passenger, etc)